# Where can I find a Bluetooth chip capable of shipping in bulk?

Tags: bluetooth

Why is it that places like Newegg can sell consumer Bluetooth products for [less than $10](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833328011), but the only Bluetooth modules I can find on Mouser or Digikey cost [close to $20](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Roving-Networks/RN-42-N/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsjLMBIknjmks6ybbLVLmSu4PQl244IRnQ=)?

I am looking for the cheapest way to support bidirectional communication via Bluetooth SPP. Does anyone know why these chips are so expensive?

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design. Question should be closed.

Comment: @LeonHeller How is finding components not related to electronic design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mass production a BT chip costs less than 75 cents. The problem is none of the vendors will work with you, you need to find a module maker who can support you. In MP (Mass Production) you can reach to 5$ level with module including antenna etc. good luck.

The key vendors to look at are CSR and BRCM (Broadcom). We use a Taiwanese module maker with one of their solutions. APMComm is the vendor, there are tons of others just look around.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What's "MP"?

Comment: BRCM = Broadcom.

Comment: MP= Mass Production

Answer (score 2):

We are currently having a similar problem. Here is what we discovered so far:

For small (e.g. prototyping) quantities eBay has quite a few modules available for as low as £5.
For production quantities there seem to be plenty of Asian vendors, it's just a matter of finding the right one. Check on places like Alibaba, as Frank mentions as low as $5 is possible with the right quantities.